# What is the first fighter jet which was built with twin engine and tail configuration?

Tags: aircraft-design, fighter

What is the very first fighter jet that pioneers the twin engine and twin vertical stabilizers over the engine just before the exhaust (like the F-14, F-15, F-22, Su-35, etc)?

Comment: as from the current answers can be seen, you might want to specify whether you are looking for also prototypes or just fighters that entered service?

Comment: Both are okay, but don't forget to clarify which one was a prototype or service aircrafts.

Comment: The Heinkel He-280 was a twin-engine twin-tail jet fighter, but like most early jets had podded engines

Comment: Not a fighter, but twin-engine and tails-over-engine: [SNCAC 1071](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNCAC_NC.1070), French/1948.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the first was probably the unconventional XP-79.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_XP-79

It never entered service of course, but does meet your criteria.

Something that kinda meets your criteria would be the [F7U Cutlass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vought_F7U_Cutlass). Twin tails and twin rear mounted engines though the tails were in separate tail booms outboard of the engines, a similar configuration to that of the [DH Sea Vixen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Sea_Vixen) and [Venom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Sea_Venom) of roughly the same period.

These did enter service.

Then there is the [XF-90](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_XF-90) which has twin rear mounted engines with a single vertical stabiliser over them. 
The Soviet [La250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavochkin_La-250) and [Tu28](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-28) had similar configuration but came later.

This also did not enter service.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the MiG-25.  Near as I know, it was the first to use the ‘four poster’ layout.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46454)

Comment: @Sean Of course it answers the question. It might not be a good answer without listing any source for this, but it still is an answer.

Comment: Downvoted because of the probably. Since you probably meant to revise this later, I look forward to upvoting once this is a solid answer. Probably.

Answer (score 1):

Prototype only: the YF-12A. This was an [A-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_A-12) derived fighter plane. The A-12 is better known for its other derivative, the SR-71 Blackbird. Both the A-12 and the SR-71 were intended for reconnaissance tasks,  but the YF-12 would have been a fighter.

With a first flight in 1963, it beats the Mig-25 by a year.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly might be the WW-2 era Me-262?  I believe the prototype had twin tails.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46452)

Comment: @Sean I don't think you're using the "not an answer"-review feature quite right. It's meant for posts that don't come close to being an answer, not for posts that do not meet your criteria for being a _good_ answer. For that you can leave a normal comment, or even downvote.

Comment: I would agree that this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Sean it is an answer. It's not the correct answer, but it is an answer.